# How can I understand the square commutative of the natural isomorphisms within the definition of an equivalence of categories?

Tags: category-theory

> **Definition:** An *equivalence of categories* consists of functors $F:C \leftrightarrows D:G$ together with natural isomorphisms
> $\eta:1_C \cong GF$, $\epsilon:FG \cong 1_D.$

Let $f:x \rightarrow y$ be a morphism in $C$, then $\eta_yf = GF(f)\eta_x$, namely, $\eta_yf\eta_x^{-1} = GF(f)$. Similarly, given a morphism $g: r \rightarrow s$ in $D$, $FG(g) = \epsilon_{FG(s)}^{-1}g\epsilon_{FG(r)}$. How can I interpret these square commutatives (of the natural isomorphisms) with respect to the *intuitive* notion of equivalence of categories?

Comment: What is your intuitive notion of equivalence of categories? What the (standard) definition that you have quoted does is to require a method for mapping diagrams in $C$ to diagrams in $D$ and vice versa that both preserve commutativity.